# SQL query performance and dropcleanbuffers

Tags: sql-server

There is a "best practice" that you have to run

```
DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

Before doing performance analysis on a SQL query.

Yet, for example, the later one DROPCLEANBUFFERS:

> Use DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS to test queries with a cold buffer cache
>   without shutting down and restarting the server.
>
> To drop clean buffers from the buffer pool, first use CHECKPOINT to
>   produce a cold buffer cache. This forces all dirty pages for the
>   current database to be written to disk and cleans the buffers. After
>   you do this, you can issue DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS command to remove all
>   buffers from the buffer pool.

I guess, this means that you will test your query as if it was the first query that has run in the server, thus the actual "real-life" impact of the query will be lower.

Is it really advisable to run the three commands to know the query cost or does it get you to a rather empirical results that have no close relation to actual query time in live environment?

Comment: I'm late to the game but feel like I should point out that if you have PLE issues in production then yes, those commands would probably be helpful for testing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I disagree it is best practice and very rarely use it.

A query that I tune should be a popular, often run one. This gives me most bang for my buck. It should rarely be run "cold" for either plan or data.

I'm testing the query execution: not the disk read system or the Query Optimiser compilation

This was asked on DBA.SE a while ago. See these please

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10820/630
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7870/630

Answer (score 7):

> Is it really advisable to run the three commands to know the query cost or does it get you to a rather empirical results that have no close relation to actual query time in live environment?

It depends.

If you don't run `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` then there is a chance that you will end up with some odd results unless you are very careful about the way that you do your performance analysis.  For example, generally speaking the second time you run a query it's going to be quicker because the required pages are probably cached in memory - running `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` helps here because it ensures that you have a consistent starting point in your testing and it ensures that your query is not artificially running quickly just because it is skipping the expensive disk access portions of your query.

Like you say however, in live environments it could be that this data is always cached and so your test is not representative of production conditions - it depends on whether or not you are analysing the performance based on the assumption that the data is frequently accessed and so will generally be cached, or infrequently accessed and so disk asscess is likely to be involved.

The short answer is that running those 3 statements can help ensure that you get consistent results while performance testing, however you shouldn't necessarily *always* run these before testing, instead you should try to understand what each one does and what impact it will have on your query when compared to a production environment.

---

As an aside, **Never** run any of those 3 statements on a production server unless you know **exactly** what you are doing!

Comment: can you explain why that's a bad idea?  Assuming the production server is not being actively used at the time

Answer (score 3):

I agree with what @gbn states in his answer, and I don't think I've ever used the three commands for anything other than demonstrating a difference between possible approaches.

In addition it would be ill-advised in most cases to run these three DBCCs on a production environment just for testing. And performance tuning queries in a test environment, with test data and test load, will often lead you to draw the wrong conclusions regarding your query, anyway.

Usually, when I tune a query, I use the profiler to get actual execution stats from live, I use SSMS to get execution plans from live and I do a few test runs (on test data) to see what differs. For the more tricky problems, I also use the Windows Performance Monitor - and always in a situation that is as close to the real one as possible. Running DBCC would just remove the tuning effort from the real deal.