# PowerShell with SQL Server Management Studio WAITFOR DELAY command

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I do not see an exact or any similar useful answer to a question like this so I am asking myself.

I am using 2 lines in Powershell ISE to run two very simple SQL scripts I wrote. I am testing how I can use the WAITFOR DELAY command in SQL to run one SQL script.. then wait a certain amount of time before running the second SQL script.

In my first SQL script I have a simple GETDATE() command that I am running before a WAITFOR DELAY command..
In my second SQL script I have the same GETDATE() command inside. Powershell ISE is then using 'Out-File' to write these 2 scripts to a .txt file so I can see if it respects the time limit I inserted into the WAITFOR DELAY in my first SQL script.

I had some trouble to avoid the error: "Invoke-Sqlcmd: Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding." … 
However, I was successful in getting a WAITFOR DELAY of '00:01:00' to work by simply putting a 'go' keyword between my SELECT GETDATE() and my WAITFOR DELAY commands.. but now that I am trying to make my script wait for **ANY** longer than 1 minute.. I get the same error I mentioned above. even 1 second longer than 1 minute will not register into the data inputted into my text files.

My goal is to get the first text file to register the time of GETDATE().. then have powershell wait 10 minutes before executing the second SQL script with GETDATE() inside.. to be able to see a 10 minute difference between the execution of the two scripts.

Could anyone help out with how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using QueryTimeout with invoke-sqlcmd ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps

Comment: I need WAITFOR DELAY because I need the first T-sql script to be working for 10 minutes before the second sql script is run. 
Powershell sleep makes a 10 minute delay between my invocations which is not what I needed help with...

Comment: I tried using your guys' suggestion about Invoke-Sqlcmd -QueryTimeout 10 … but it runs the first and second sql scripts at the same exact time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers who have the same problem.. you have to use -QueryTimeout **0**  *exactly* right after your

Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile '__.sql' ___________ …

for it to work. It will not work anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Invoke-Sqlcmd` from the [SqlServer module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer) available on the PowerShell Gallery, you should be able to specify the `-QueryTimeout` parameter, which lets you specify a time out up to 65535 seconds (~18 hours). I'm not sure when this was added, but I know it's missing in the SQLPS module/snap-in from SQL Server 2008 R2.

If that doesn't work, you would need to code your own version using the .Net SqlClient class. The problem with that is that it doesn't understand the `GO` batch separator since that's not T-SQL.

Keep in mind, too, that the database itself might have it's own query timeout.

Also, if you just want to wait 10 minutes, then doing this really should suffice:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd ...
Start-Sleep -Seconds 600
Invoke-Sqlcmd ...
```

Finally, if you're testing performance, bear in mind that this type of test is going to have extremely variable results. If your SQL Server hasn't needed to use the memory, it's very likely that your query would remain in the cache pool for 10 minutes (or much longer).

For example, if you're trying to determine cold query performance, this isn't the best method. You need to use DBCC commands to force the server to ignore it's own cache or invalidate it's cache. I would read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042657/sql-query-performance-and-dropcleanbuffers) as well as the two linked questions in the accepted answer. In particular I'd agree with the assessment that cold query performance shouldn't be that big of a deal since, somewhat by definition, it's not run very often.

Comment: I tried using your guys' suggestion about Invoke-Sqlcmd -QueryTimeout 10 … but it runs the first and second sql scripts at the same exact time

Comment: @Dan `-QueryTimeout` doesn't eliminate the need for `WAITFOR DELAY`.  It just allows you to avoid the timeout error that you're getting.  Also `-QueryTimeout 10` is a 10 second timeout.  You need 600 seconds for 10 minutes.  You may still run into timeout issues, however, because [the default server-side query timeout is 10 minutes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-query-timeout-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017).